# Compiler Error after upgrading from .Net Core 2 to .Net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I upgraded from .Net Core 2 to .Net 6.  One of the errors that it caused was this:

> Error CS1106  Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static
> class

It is happening on the `public class BookController` line.

So I did some research on the Microsoft site and I removed the `static` keyword from the `LateFee` method.

But that doesn't fix the error.

Is there anything else I need to do?

Here is my class:

```
public class BookController
    : LibraryController<BookClub, Books>
{

    public BookController(BookConfig<BookClub> ctx) 
        : base(ctx)
    {
    }

    private static bool LateFee(BookClub original, Books b)
    {
        return original.Date?.Id != b.CheckoutDate.TrimToNull();
    }
}
```

Here is the parent class:

```
public class LibraryController()

    [HttpPost("byLocation/{id}")]
    public IActionResult PostBookRequest(this Int32 id)
    {
        using (var tran = Session.BeginTransaction()) {
            foreach (var book in LibraryService.CreateHold(id)) {
                Session.Save(book);
            }
            tran.Commit();
            return NoContent();
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the error ? I can't see it on my editor

Comment: Extension methods contain the `this` keyword as part of the first parameter in an extension method's parameter list.  Are you sure you *haven't* declared such a method in this class?

Comment: Did you type that code or copy it? For this to be an extension method, there is a `this` missing.

Comment: See the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1106).

Comment: Look for a method that looks like `<access modifier> static Type MethodName( this SomeType argName, ...` Move it into a static non-generic class.

Comment: @Fildor the parent class has that `this` keyword. Could that be it?

Comment: Post the code for the parent class.

Comment: If you post it, we can tell. But it sounds promising.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that going from .NET Core 2 to .NET 6 would give you a compile error like this. That parent class you have posted would never have compiled in any version of C#/.NET. You need to provide a [mre] otherwise this question will be closed.

Comment: @DavidG I know I'm sorry, it's so odd.  I did check `git` to see the last change to that class and the classes that inherit from it, and the last change was back in 2018.

Comment: Even the line `public class LibraryController()` has never been valid C# code, that has NEVER compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IActionResult PostBookRequest(this Int32 id)
```

Remove the `this` from that line, it's a syntactic error in .Net Core 2 and it remains a syntax error in .Net6.

Comment: thank you, so you mean so it looks like this? `public IActionResult PostBookRequest(Int32 id)` ?

Comment: Or even better, `public IActionResult PostBookRequest(int id)`